# I don't understand why I don't have scope to this global variable and is there an alternative?

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="aj.xsl"?>
<Test>
  <Highlight>
    <HighlightName>Name 1</HighlightName>
    <HighlightName>Name 2</HighlightName>
    <HighlightName>Name 3</HighlightName>
    <HighlightName>Name 5</HighlightName>
    <HighlightName>Name 6</HighlightName>
  </Highlight>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 1</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 6</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 2</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 7</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 3</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 8</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 4</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 9</Name>
  </Date>
  <Date>
    <Name>Name 5</Name>
  </Date>
</Test>
```

And some test XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="4.01"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
    doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Workbook-S-140-Version2.css"/>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:for-each select="Test/Highlight/HighlightName">
          <xsl:variable name="strHighlightName" select="."/>
          <p>Start of list for {$strHighlightName}</p>
          <xsl:for-each select="Test/Date">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Name">
    <p>
      <xsl:if test="$strHighlightName=.">
        <xsl:text>**</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>

  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The sample is short to convey the issue. In the final scenario my files are more detailed.

The basic concept I was trying to implement was to loop through a list of known names that I wanted to highlight. Then, amongst other things, I wanted to indicated if any of the names elsewhere were one of the highlighted ones. So I tried the above but sadly the variable **strHighlightName** is not visible to the **Name** template.

I realise I can use parameters and feed the value in to the template, but in the real world I would have to cascade this param all teh way down into the template can calls Name.

Since I can't use this approach, can I do it differently? For example, can I do something like this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="Name">
    Does "." match any of the names in the "//Highlight/HighlightName" section?
    If yes
        Text "** "
</xsl:template>
```

Does that make sense? It would avoid the need for needed a variable and or passing parameters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I realise I can use parameters and feed the value in to the template, but in the real world I would have to cascade this param all the way down into the template can calls Name.
```

In XSLT 1.0, cascading it through all the intermediate templates is what you have to do.

In XSLT 2.0, you can use tunnel parameters, which tunnel through from the first template to the second without needing to be explicitly mentioned in all the intermediate ones.

So, see if an XSLT 2.0 processor is available in your application environment.